# Importing Excel Spreadsheet containing Array Formulas

Tags: bugs, import, excel

**Bug introduced in ?.?.? and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

Has anyone had any success with importing an Excel Spreadsheet holding an array formula into Mathematica?

The Syntax I'm using is

`Import["test.xlsx", {"Sheets", "SheetWithArrayFormula"}]`

The error that is returned is: Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as XLSX format. >>

EDIT

A sample excel file can be found here:
http://temp-share.com/show/gFHKQZS0Y

Comment: Please provide a small sample Excel file for testing.

Comment: I've made an edit to contain a link with a sample excel file.

Comment: I have been informed by WRI that the reported issue has been resolved; a quick check done by me revealed no difficulties with array formulas in excel files being imported. I thus added an updated bug header.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems there are some troubles with the XLSX format, whereas using the old XLS it works fine. Look the following tests:

```
Import["c:\\tempmath\\test.xlsx", "Sheets"]
```

> {"SheetWithArrayFormula"}

```
Import["c:\\tempmath\\test.xlsx", {"Sheets", "SheetWithArrayFormula"}]
```

> Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as XLSX format. >>
>
> $Failed

```
Import["c:\\tempmath\\test.xlsx", "Formulas"]
```

> {{{"", "", ""}, {"", "", "A2:A4*B2:B4"}, {"", "", "A2:A4*B2:B4"}, {"", "", 
>      "A2:A4*B2:B4"}}}

```
Import["c:\\tempmath\\test.xlsx"]
```

> Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as XLSX format. >>
>
> $Failed

after converting the XLSX to XLS

```
Import["c:\\tempmath\\test.xls"]
```

> {{{"X", "Y", "Formula"}, {1., 0.1, 0.1}, {2., 0.2, 0.4}, {3., 0.3, 0.9}}}

```
Import["c:\\tempmath\\test.xls", "Formulas"]
```

> {{{"", "", ""}, {"", "", "A2:A4*B2:B4"}, {"", "", "A2:A4*B2:B4"}, {"", "", 
>      "A2:A4*B2:B4"}}}

```
Import["c:\\tempmath\\test.xls", {"Sheets", "SheetWithArrayFormula"}]
```

> {{"X", "Y", "Formula"}, {1., 0.1, 0.1}, {2., 0.2, 0.4}, {3., 0.3, 0.9}}

generally when you want to look which elements are available into an external file, use the second Import argument "Elements"

```
Import["c:\\tempmath\\test.xlsx", "Elements"]
```

> {"Data", "FormattedData", "Formulas", "Images", "Sheets"}

So, I guess the problem is not due to the Excel file contents (array formulas), rather to some wrong behavior of Import and XLSX.

Comment: I wonder if there is a workaround using `"Data"`?

Comment: Unfortunately, even adding "Data" it doesn't work. However, you can convert the file to xls format and it works.

Comment: Yes, but that's going to be very unpopular with anyone hoping to use Mathematica for visualizing a lot of data stored in Excel. It is clearly a bug in Mathematica.

Comment: @Verbeia that's right, I already sent a report to WRI technical support.

Comment: This bug is still present in 10.1. Any chance to get fixed in 10.2 ?

Comment: I just received an answer from WRI technical support: The issue is known and they hope it will be fixed by a future release. Hope dies last as they say.